# React: facing issues using css styles in jsx

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have been trying to use external css on my React project. I am using webpack with babel. I have configured css, js and jsx loaders on my project. As a matter of fact my project is able to compiled successfully yet I couldn't able to style applied on my html.

Here is my style-header.css file:

```
.LogoMargin {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here is my jsx file in which I want to use css style

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import logo from '../resources/images/logo.png';
import '../resources/style/style-header.css';

class Header extends Component {
  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <span>
          <img className="LogoMargin" src={logo} height="60" width="200" alt="logo" />
        </span>
        <TextField
          id="search"
          label="Search"
          type="search"
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Here webpack config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry:  __dirname + "/app/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true,
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + "/index.tmpl.html"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true,
    stats: {colors: true},
    hot: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide webpack config

Comment: Just updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Add style loader for handling css as well.

Because you didn't provide webpack version, I cannot provide any code, but I'm sure you will figure out how to use it.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader

Answer (score 0):

You should add "style-loader" for your webpack configuration. You can provide it in array as the following. Also, I have an example in this repo:

https://github.com/burakhanalkan/simple-react-materialui-app-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: [
        "style-loader",
        "css-loader"
   ]
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to solve this problem as proposed by answers to use [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) and also I made some changes to my webpack config file which are as follow:

```
test: /\.css$/,
exclude: /node_modules/,
use: [
  { loader: "style-loader" },
  { loader: "css-loader" ,
    query: {
      modules: true,
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    }}
]
```

But I wonder when I set up react environment using **Create React App** I was able to use styles without using css module loader.